# how to represent map'content vertically in a excel sheet

Tags: java

I have a map whose content should be represented vertically rather than in a horizontal layout

```
Multimap<Integer, String> map = getMap();
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("companyInsurence");
            XSSFRow row;
            Set < Integer > keyid = map.keySet();
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);

        Cell InitialCell=row.createCell(0);
        InitialCell.setCellValue("id");

        Cell InitialCell1=row.createCell(1);
        InitialCell1.setCellValue("date");

        int rowid = 1;
        for (Integer key : keyid){
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
            Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
            cell0.setCellValue(key);
            Collection<String>  objectList = map.get(key);

            int cellid = 1;
            for (Object obj : objectList)
            {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                if(obj!=null){
                    cell.setCellValue(obj.toString());
                }else{
                    cell.setCellValue("  ");
                }
            }
        }
```

amd map content is
{12=[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6],13=[123456,988,65,hgg,91]}

so excel sheet shows data as

```
id       date
12       1   2   4   ....
13       123456  988  65
```

So instead of this i want something like this

```
id   date
12   1
12   2
12   3
12   4
12   5
12   6
:
:
:
:
13  65
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a row for each value, not each key.

```
int rowid = 1;
for (Integer key : keyid){
    Collection<String>  objectList = map.get(key);
    for (Object obj : objectList)
    {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
        Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
        cell0.setCellValue(key);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        if(obj!=null){
            cell.setCellValue(obj.toString());
        }else{
            cell.setCellValue("  ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't run this.